# How to change default options of a document class?

Tags: fontsize, documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm trying to define a custom class `rs-book.cls` based on a standard class `book.cls` and would like to change some of the default options.
For instance, by default (with no options given), the command `\documentclass{book}` produces a `10pt`, `twoside`, `onecolumn` document.
Let's say that in my case, with command `\documentclass{rs-book}`, I would like to produce a `12pt`, `oneside`, `twocolumn` document by default, **but** with the ability overwrite these options (as in `\documentclass[10pt]{rs-book}` would produce a `10pt` font document).

The problem is that I can't recreate this behavior as it gets pretty confusing: in the example below the command `\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn]{rs-book}` keeps the default `12pt` and `twocolumn` values, but successfully applies the `twoside` option.

MWE:

`rs-book.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{rs-book}

% Read all options to rs-book class and pass them to book class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
% Execute the code for each option
\ProcessOptions\relax
% Load book class with fixed options
\LoadClass[12pt,oneside,twocolumn]{book}
```

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn]{rs-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A modification of book.cls}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{rs-book}

\def\rs@ptsize{12pt} % default value
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\rs@ptsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\rs@ptsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\rs@ptsize{12pt}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[\rs@ptsize,oneside,twocolumn]{book}

\endinput
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One remark though: your solution manually hardcodes fontsizes (not just the default one) in the custom class. Is there any possibility of some sort of 'option inheritance'? For instance, maybe a `13pt` option becomes available in the future for the `book` class. This means that I would have to edit my custom class and add an additional entry for `13pt` option.